# Connect to geckodriver with selenium js

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm not an expert of Selenium, so I may miss something here.

- One of the software in the corp starts a firefox with Geckodriver.
- I would like to connect / attach to this browser from my JavaScript code.

I know the port where the Webserver starts and the sessions identifier.

I try to connect from JS:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

void async function() {
    let driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').usingServer('http://localhost:55849/').build();

    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);

    driver.quit();
}();
```

The connection is not successful. What I can think is that this code tries to start a new instance.

There is an error message:

```
SessionNotCreatedError: Session is already started
```

Any idea how I can connect to the existing one? And control it?

I've tried everything from the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

I even tried to connect `http://localhost:55849/wd/hub` but then I received `WebDriverError: HTTP method not allowed` error

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/07a18746ff756e90fd79ef253a328bd7dfa9e6dc/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/index.js#L255 usingServer() is expecting the Selenium Server URL (hub) and not the geckodriver server url . Communication flow JS script --> selenium server --> geckodriver --> firefox

Comment: You are right, this is the port I try to connect. I updated it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the [selenium-webdriver/http](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/http/index.html)

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const http= require('selenium-webdriver/http')

let sessionId = '9aad751d-eb9b-4c92-92f3-298c733f6ec7';
let url = 'http://localhost:57538';

let driver = new webdriver.WebDriver(
    sessionId,
    new http.Executor(Promise.resolve(url)
        .then(
            url => new http.HttpClient(url, null, null))
    )
);
```